# testNG.xml method description in include tag

Tags: testng

I tried to include method description in the testng.xml as follows.

```
<class name="com.RegressionSuite">
    <methods>
        <include name="AutTC00" **description="method desc"** />
    </methods>
</class>
```

and attempted to retrieve using getDescription() method of XmlInclude

ISuite getTests() > XmlTest getClasses() >  XmlClass getIncludedMethods() > XmlInclude getDescription()

but getting null.

Please suggest if it is possible ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: You may have found an issue. I created a new ticket on the project: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1112